# How to know the last x & y values at the end of a dragNdrop?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drag-and-drop

So I have a view with an *UITableView* on which I am able to add some objects (they come from my nib: *SelectPostIt.xib*). 
These objects are draggable and what I want to do later is, when I'll drag then drop the object on a row of the *TableView* , it will add the object into the good row etc.

So I thought about many solutions and the one who seems to me the best is to catch the last coordinates of where I dropped my finger (the rest of the problem is another story :') ).

Here's my question, do I need to add something in my method who handle the dragNdrop of my object to know where I dropped it?
Here's my method:

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
[recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self]; }
```

Every help will be welcome, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the state property of `UIGestureRecognizer`, if its `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` that means your panning has been ended, so you can choose that point of location as drop point.

```
-(IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        // Just take the Coordintate
        CGPoint centerPointOfView = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
NSLog(@"X - %f, Y - %f",centerPointOfView.x,centerPointOfView.y);
    }
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self];

}
```

Comment: So if I understand everything, here, your "if" is to know if the drag ended so, if we dropped the object right? But if I want to see these coordinates, where and how can I add something like a NSLog(@"x: y:", x, y) please?

Comment: Check the `centerPointOfView ` its the one tha you r looking for.

Comment: How can I pick up the x and y values of this centerPointOfView so?

Comment: See i updated the answer and added Log. just need to take centerPointOfVeiew.x for X and similar for Y